# Call internal javascript function from java code

Tags: javascript, java

I have to call a javascript function named `function startPolling()` and created into hill.js file (/Demo MM/src/main/webapp/static/assets/js/hill.js) from java code. How can i do?Thanks
I'm using this code but receive exception

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    if (!(engine instanceof Invocable)) {
      System.out.println("Invoking methods is not supported.");
      return "500";
    }
    Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
    String scriptPath = "/Demo MM/src/main/webapp/static/assets/js/hill.js";

    try {
        engine.eval("load('" + scriptPath + "')");
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        return "500";
    }
```

Comment: what is your javascript function doing? it makes sense to execute it in server instead of the client?

Comment: it does polling and sets html value and label color

Comment: so answer to second questions is... no.... right?

Comment: right, for now I use polling method for all the time

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding differences between client and server in java applications....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the correct working directory to begin with. I get your code working.

To output working directory:

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
          System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```